# Inequality involving determinant and matrices?

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant, symmetric-matrices, convexity-inequality

Here is the statement :

> Let $A\in \mathcal{S}_n^{++}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B \in
>  \mathcal{S}_n^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ then we have the following inequality :
>    $(\det(A+B))^{\frac{1}{n}}\ge
>  (\det(A))^{\frac{1}{n}}+(\det(B))^{\frac{1}{n}}$, $\ n\ge 1$.

Is it a well-known inequality and are there references about it ?

**NB** : *$\mathcal{S}_n^{++}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of symmetric matrices whose eigenvalues are $>0$ and $\mathcal{S}_n^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of the matrices who eigenvalues are $\ge 0$*.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you clarify your notation?

Comment: Minkowski determinant theorem. see refs in this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/65430/33248)

Comment: @achillehui Thank you, very interesting and powerful !